How to run nightwatch on Github actions with containerized postgres?
I have nightwatch working locally, but I want to run it in Github actions as well. I connect to postgres in my test using Docker. Running the Github action gives me this error:
Run xvfb-run --auto-servernum npm run test:ci

> diswantin@0.1.0 test:ci
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test server-test start:test http://localhost:8811 'nightwatch -e ci.chrome'

1: starting server using command "npm run start:test"
and when url "[ 'http://localhost:8811' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "nightwatch -e ci.chrome"


> diswantin@0.1.0 start:test
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8811 node dist/index.js

 App listening on http://localhost:8811
HEAD / 200 - - 30.794 ms
Running   ci.chrome: smoke.ts  
┌ ────────────────── ✖  ci.chrome: smoke.ts  ─────────┐
│                                                     │
│   [Smoke test] Test Suite                           │
│   ──────────────────────────────────────────────    │
│   Using: chrome (133.0.6868.0) on LINUX.            │
│   – can create task                                 │
│   ✖ ci.chrome [Smoke test] can create task (66ms)   │
│                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  ️TEST FAILURE (2.721s): 
   - 1 error during execution; 
   - 0 tests failed; 
   - 0/1 tests passed

   ✖ 1) test/smoke

   – can create task (66ms)

   Error
   unknown error

  - OTHER ERRORS:
  Error
    Error
   connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433

    Error location:
    /__w/diswantin-web/diswantin-web/test/smoke.ts:7
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
     5 | 
     6 | async function createAuthSession() {
     7 |   const userId = await createUser({ 
     8 |     googleId: faker.string.uuid(),
     9 |     email: faker.internet.email(),
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––


 Wrote HTML report file to: /__w/diswantin-web/diswantin-web/tests_output/nightwatch-html-report/index.html

Error: Command failed with exit code 1: nightwatch -e ci.chrome
    at makeError (/__w/diswantin-web/diswantin-web/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/__w/diswantin-web/diswantin-web/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: nightwatch -e ci.chrome',
  command: 'nightwatch -e ci.chrome',
  escapedCommand: '"nightwatch -e ci.chrome"',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

deploy.yml:
name:  Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:

jobs:
  e2e-test:
    name: ⚫️ End-to-end test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:22-bookworm
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - 5433:5432
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_DB: diswantin
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - name:  Install sudo package
        run: apt update && apt install sudo
      - name: ⬇️ Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.2.2
      - name: ⎔ Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4.1.0
        with:
          cache: npm
          node-version: 22
      - name:  Install Chromedriver dependencies
        run: >-
          sudo apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6
          libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1
          libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4
          libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1
          libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3
          libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates
          fonts-liberation libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget ca-certificates
      - name:  Set up Chromedriver
        uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@v1.7.2
        with:
          install-chromedriver: true
      - name:  Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: ️ Install Xvfb
        run: sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
      - name:  Copy test env vars
        run: cp env/example.env env/test.env
      - name: ️ Push database schema
        run: npm run db:push -- --force
        env:
          NODE_ENV: test
      - name: ⚙️ Build app
        run: npm run build
        env:
          NODE_ENV: test
      - name:  Run end-to-end tests
        run: xvfb-run --auto-servernum npm run test:ci

package.json:
{
  "name": "diswantin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "run-s build:*",
    "build:remix": "remix vite:build",
    "build:server": "tsx ./scripts/build-server.ts",
    "start:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8811 node dist/index.js",
    "db:push": "drizzle-kit push",
    "test:ci": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test server-test start:test http://localhost:8811 'nightwatch -e ci.chrome'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@remix-run/express": "^2.14.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.14.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.14.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.36.3",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "isbot": "^5.1.17",
    "pg": "^8.13.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^9.2.0",
    "@nightwatch/mobile-helper": "^1.0.0",
    "@nightwatch/testing-library": "^0.1.1",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.14.0",
    "@remix-run/route-config": "^2.14.0",
    "@swc/core": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.28.1",
    "esbuild": "0.24.0",
    "nightwatch": "^3.9.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^7.0.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^2.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "tsx": "^4.19.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "vite": "^5.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.0.0"
  }
}

nightwatch.conf.js:
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ["test", "nightwatch"],
  page_objects_path: [],
  custom_commands_path: [],
  custom_assertions_path: [],
  plugins: ["@nightwatch/testing-library"],
  globals_path: "",
  webdriver: {},
  test_workers: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      disable_error_log: false,
      launch_url: "http://localhost:8811",

      screenshots: {
        enabled: false,
        path: "screens",
        on_failure: true,
      },

      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
      },

      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        server_path: "",
      },
    },

    "ci.chrome": {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
          args: ["--no-sandbox", "--headless"],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};


env/example.env:
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5433/diswantin"

It's able to connect to postgres when I push the database schema changes, but it can't reconnect inside the test. Is xvfb-run interfering with the database? How do I run nightwatch on Github actions with access to a postgres database?
